# Probabilities, dependence and independence

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Given the following about the three events $A$,$B$, and $C$:

- $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$,
- $P(A \cap C) = P(A \mid C)P(C)$, and
- $P(B \cap C) = P(B \mid C)P(C)$

In other words, events $A$ and $B$ are independent, but $A$ and $C$ are dependent, as well as $B$ and $C$.

Assume P(A), P(B), and P(C) are known. Also, assume the right hand sides (RHS) of above given equations are all known.

Requirement:

Find $P(A \cap B \mid C)$, noting that $P(C \mid A \cap B)$ is unknown?

My thoughts:

Applying Bayes' theorem:

$P(A \cap B \mid C) = P(A \cap B \cap C)/P(C)$

However, the numerator in RHS is unknown. So, in order to find it, we need to express it in terms of the three given equations above.

I tried to apply below formula

$P(A \cap B \cap C)=P(A \mid B \cap C) P(B \mid C)  P(C)$

But the RHS still has the unknown component $P(A \mid B \cap C)$

Any idea please?

Comment: This is my 2nd question in this forum which I receive 0 answers! Could it mean that my question is difficult? I think it should not be difficult for probability experts. Any hint is very much appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean by $P(A)$ measurable? You mean one could some how have an estimate of the value of $P(A)$?

Comment: It means this probability is known. Thanks for asking, I will edit to reflect this fact.

Comment: So far, we only know $P(A\cap B), P(A\cap B) , P(B\cap C) ,P(A),P(B),P(C)$ and we want to know $P(A\cap B\cap C)$. By drawing Venn's diagram, we still need to know $P(A\cup B\cup C)$. So I think the problem does not have an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It would be nice if you please clarify how $A \cup B \cup C$ is related to $A \cap B \cap C$. I kind of find it difficult to imagine without the use of set subtractions and negation operators.

Comment: $P(A\cup B \cup C) =P(A)+P(B)+P(C) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) -P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$.  Try to draw Venn's diagram to understand it.@zoli 's example could lead you to have different value of $P(A\cap B \cap C)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not have a solution: Even if we have $P(A)$,$P(B)$,$P(C)$,$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(C)$, $P(A\cap C)$, and $P(B\cap C)$ fixed, $P(A\cap B \cap C)$ may still vary.

Consider $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ (endowed with the uniform distribution) and $A,B,C$ such that $C$ has two disjoint parts as shown below.

Apparently $A$ and $B$ are independent. If one shifts $C$ parallel to itself horizontally (within a certain interval) then neither $P(A)$ nor $P(B)$ nor $P(C)$ nor $P(B\cap C)$ nor $P(A\cap B)$ change. However, $P(A\cap B \cap C)$ does.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful insight; But if you slide C horizontally, wouldn't $P(C)$ and hence $P(A \cup C)$ be changing too? Wouldn't this result in a constant $P(A \cup B \cup C)$? Just wondering, and thanks again for your valuable input.

Comment: (1) The height of both parts of $C$ is the same. I tried to express this on the figure. (2) If you shift $C$ such a way that it stays within the square then its measure doesn't change. (3) If you shift $C$ then it goes out of $A$ partly but another part of it (with the same measure) goes into $A$. Of course you have to do it moderately... (4) The common part of $B$ and $C$ will not change if you keep $C$ within the square.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to say that shifting horizontally means "horizontally", that is no motion up or down is allowed...